My coinbase wallet is compromised I have presale not launched still in wallet can they be saved
My seed phrase was compromised via a phishing scam I fell victim to trying to claim my cybro presale .I still have wall street pepe  presale not launched in wallet they took all my other crypto but can I somehow save my wallstreet pepe at launch some how please help

This question is similar to: I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum or Uniswap. What to do?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You should contact the launch team and ask if it is possible to change the wallet. It is up to the team if they can do it or not. Take into account that anyone with your seed phrase will be able to impersonate your wallet.
